# How to create an input function for char matrix (2D array)?

Tags: c, pointers, pass-by-reference, dynamic-memory-allocation, function-definition

I am new to the C language and I wrote the following code, but, unfortunately, it doesn't work. The errors are C6011 Dereferencing null pointer and C6386 Buffer overrun while writing for this line:

```
arr[i] = (char*)malloc(m * sizeof(char));
```

and C6385 Reading invalid data from arr and C6011 for this line:

```
scanf_s("%c ", &arr[i][j],1);
```

Also, when I input 1000 rows with 1000 characters the compiler breaks down. How am I supposed to improve that?

Here's the code:

```
void individualTestCaseInput(char** arr, int n, int m) {
    arr = (char**)malloc(n * sizeof(char*));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = (char*)malloc(m * sizeof(char));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            scanf_s("%c ", &arr[i][j],1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't you need a 3-star agument for that? You are overwriting the argument as if it is a local variable, and nothing gets to caller. Easier and more clear would be : return the 2-star pointer as the function value. `char **individualTestCaseInput(int n, int m)`

Answer (score 0):

The function parameter `char **arr` is a local variable of the function that is initialized by the value of an argument expression. That is the argument is passed by value to the function. Changes of the local variable do not influence on the original argument.

Either declare and define the function the following way (that is accepting the original pointer by reference through a pointer to it)

```
void individualTestCaseInput( char ***arr, int n, int m ) 
{
    *arr = malloc(n * sizeof(char *));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        ( *arr )[i] = malloc(m * sizeof(char));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            scanf_s(" %c", &( *arr )[i][j],1);
        }
    }
}
```

And call it like

```
char **arr;
//...
individualTestCaseInput( &arr, n, m );
```

Or declare and define the function the following way

```
char ** individualTestCaseInput( int n, int m ) 
{
    char **arr = malloc(n * sizeof(char *));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = malloc(m * sizeof(char));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            scanf_s(" %c", &arr[i][j],1);
        }
    }

    return arr;
}
```

and call it like

```
char **arr = individualTestCaseInput( n, m );
```

You could also include checks into the function whether the memory was allocated successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Build from first principles when confused! You need to add an extra `*` to the function parameter.

- You have array elements of `char`.
- You then want to have a row of these (or column, whatever order). This is `char *`, although when writing it is cleaner to write e.g. `char row[]`.
- You have some number of these rows, `char **` aka `char matrix[][]`.
- You then want to pass the pointer to the function, so `char ***` aka `char *matrix_ptr[][]`.
- Your function just then needs to set `*matrix_ptr = malloc(...)`. I would suggest returning it instead.

If you *do* end up still using `matrix_ptr`, you'll need to use the `*` when referencing array elements through the pointer, like `(*matrix_ptr)[][]`.